# Escape from [escaping]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Some of the uses of the undefined [escaping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/escaping) tag look like they should have used [escape-sequences](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/escape-sequences)  The rest don't seem to have a whole lot in common.  Can someone look at this and see if they can make sense of what's there?  Is there a useful common thread that just needs a wiki definition, or do we need to replace it with several more specific tags, or is it unnecessary and can just be deleted?